# Replacing excel column names in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, database

I'd like to upload data from an excel file to a database table and I am using below code to do so. However, the columns in excel file use special characters and spaces which SQL does not like of course. Is there any way to map/replace column headers like `Int. Q1 (A)` , `Int. Q2 (B)` , `Int. Q3 (C)` , `Int. Q4 (D)` in the stored procedure as not to get *invalid column name* errors when running the statement? Note: It is not possible for me to change column headers in the excel file itself. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] ([Column_A], [Column_B], [Column_C], [Column_D])
SELECT A.[Int. Q1 (A)], A.[Int. Q2 (B)], A.[Int. Q3 (C)], A.[Int. Q4 (D)] FROM OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Directory\Quantities\TestFile.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'select * from [Sheet$]') AS A;
```

Comment: What are the results of this query? `EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', ''Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Directory\Quantities\TestFile.xlsx;HDR=YES'', ''select * from [Sheet$]'') AS A';` Specifically, the [name] column.

Comment: Instead of referencing column names, is it possible to reference column index values like 0, 1, 2?

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, the fullstop special character is recognized with # in MS SQL Server. Changing [Int. Q1 (A)] to [Int# Q1 (A)] and the rest of the columns did the trick.

Comment: You can only reference the ordinal position of a column in the `ORDER BY`, as columns don't have an ordinal position until the `SELECT` is processed in the logical processing order.

Comment: Awesome! Glad that helped you get the answer. Most likely it was ACE/OLEDB making the change, rather than SQL Server as (possibly foolishly) SQL Server is more than happy to have a column with a `.` in the name; provided you properly quote the object.

Comment: I need to execute at least 10 of these insert statements in a .sql file to upload data from 10 separate excel files to one database table (a batch job will pick it up overnight). Is there a clever way to move the successfully processed excel files to a 'PROCESSED' directory and the ones which encountered an error/didn't upload to an 'ERROR' archive on the database server?

Comment: That's a very different question, but sounds like now you want to go down an ETL process by using a tool such as SSIS.

Comment: Change flag  'HDR=NO' and use default column names